# Service Account flow - 2 Legged Oauth Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth, google-smart-home

I want to get the Oauth token from the GCP client credentials.
[Reference](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google?tab=doc#example-package-ServiceAccount)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/supreetdeshpande/Downloads/esp-rainmaker-97663-2f539a842d10.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
    response, err := client.Get("...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(response)
}
```

I have downloaded the credentials and they work well with the Google Actions Test suite.
I tried this code but I'm getting `2020/06/02 01:58:56 Get ...: unsupported protocol scheme ""`

Often these errors seem to arise due to incorrect token URLs. My configured URI is `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` which conforms as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

Works well with `oauth2l fetch --credentials ~/Downloads/esp-rainmaker-97663-2f539a842d10.json --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/homegraph`

To confirm the scheme I replaced ("...") above with the actual URL,
    `response, err := client.Get("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token")`
It resulted in the below error

```
&{404 Not Found 404 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map[Alt-Svc:[h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"] Content-Length:[0] Content-Type:[text/html] Date:[Tue, 02 Jun 2020 18:43:01 GMT] Server:[scaffolding on HTTPServer2] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[0]] {0xc0002a6280} 0 [] false false map[] 0xc00011e300 0xc0000b2370}
```

Had logged an issue [here](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/423) as well.
Is there something I could be missing on my part?

Comment: It's not clear that the error is related to authentication. Are you sure the URL passed to Get includes the scheme (i.e. http:// or https://)?

Comment: Yes, it reads from the config file which has the https:// scheme.

Comment: Snippet from the JSON file - `"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",`
Tried printing the `client` before the Get call and it did print the correct URL too.

Comment: So changing the URL fixed the error then. You're not supposed to call the token endpoint yourself. The client will do that transparently as required. Requests to the token endpoint are POST requests, so getting a 404 response isn't too surprising (but again, don't worry about it). Just make the request that requires authorization using a URL including the scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I realized that the http client is not to be used to connect directly.
JWT offers another API, tokensource which should be used.

This reference was incorrect as I was confused with the goDoc's service account  [example](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2/google?tab=doc#example-package-ServiceAccount).

The code should look like this->

```
func GoogleAccessTokenFromJSON(secret_json string, scope string) (string, error){
  data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(secret_json)
  if err != nil {
      return "",err
  }

  conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, scope)
  if err != nil {
      return "",err
  }

  res := conf.TokenSource(oauth2.NoContext)
  token,err := res.Token()
  if err != nil {
      return "",err
  }

  return token.AccessToken, err
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/280

Answer (score 0):

There is also a possibility of missing permissions which was my case.

```
conf.Subject = "email"
```

*email = Email you want the svc account to pretend to be*
Add this to your **config** and `client.Get(..)` works!